# discount coupon code is not working on checkout page

Tags: magento2.2, discount, coupon-codes

My discount coupon code is not working on the checkout page, if I'm clicking on the apply button or canceling the button, both buttons are not working and the coupon code is working properly on the cart page

Answer (score 0):

Check your console for errors you may need to redeploy the content

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```